# Play Framework Ubuntu Rogue Process

Tags: scala, ubuntu, playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I've packaged my Play application using the [sbt-native-packager Debian Plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/debian.html). I installed the `.deb` file using the typical `sudo dpkg -i tyrion_1.0-SNAPSHOT_all.deb`. Once I did that, it created the daemon user and group and started the process as per the following:

```
aczerwon@vps57610:~/work/tyrion/target$ sudo dpkg -i tyrion_1.0-SNAPSHOT_all.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package tyrion.
(Reading database ... 53135 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack tyrion_1.0-SNAPSHOT_all.deb ...
Unpacking tyrion (1.0-SNAPSHOT) ...
Setting up tyrion (1.0-SNAPSHOT) ...
Creating system group: tyrion
Creating system user: tyrion in tyrion with tyrion user-daemon and shell /bin/false
tyrion start/running, process 30525
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
```

I see a `java` process running at 50% - which is nuts because the app should be idle. I'm assuming it's using the `application.conf` configuration but I get a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when I try to hit the website.

#### Process is Starting and Stopping

Watching `top`, I now see the CPU is pinned because the process is starting and dying over and over. The `pid` is changing and VisualVM can't see it - it's not listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error is probably due to miss configuration of play. See [sbt-native-packager docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/topics/play.html) and [play pid configuration](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production#Play-PID-Configuration).

### Example configuration

```
javaOptions in Universal ++= Seq(
  // Since play uses separate pidfile we have to provide it with a proper path
  s"-Dpidfile.path=/var/run/${packageName.value}/play.pid",

  // setting the http port explicitly
  "-Dhttp.port=9000"
)
```

For the high CPU utilization I would recommend profiling the app with VisualVM or MissionControl to see what's going on.

### Update

For play applications the `PID` file must be named `play.pid` otherwise play doesn't start up.

Comment: I made the appropriate changes - see my [build.sbt](https://github.com/andyczerwonka/tyrion/blob/master/build.sbt#L28). All the directories are created properly with the appropriate permissions. When I install it, the java process starts but `/var/run/tyrion` is empty.

Comment: Which ubuntu version are you running on? Ubuntu switched from upstart to systemd between 14.10 and 15.04.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Looking at `top`, it looks like the PID is changing, so the process is starting and dying over and over, hence the pinned CPU.

Comment: It works!! I changed the name of the PID - which broke everything. Changing it back to `play.pid` makes it work.

Comment: So play is depending on a fixed name of the PID? I couldn't find any references in the sbt-native-packager code base. It would be awesome if you open a small PR adding this to the docs.

Comment: I'm going to do that, yes.